# Print page header from second page in Jasper Report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a title band with some text and an image. My requirement is to print only that image (i.e on the top of title band) on each page but the text will get printed on the first page only.

Note: I can use page header to print the image on each page but then the image will get printed below the text for the first page. But, the image should always be on the top(it will be on the top for rest of the pages except the first page if I use page header).

**I can put the image in the page header also so  I just need to suppress the page header for the first page using page number report variable.**

*I tried this $V{PAGE_NUMBER}==2 but it didn't work.*

Comment: You can use page header band

Comment: I need to print the page header before title.

Comment: Is there any way to suppress the page header for the first page?

Comment: `I need to print the page header before title.` - In this case you can place image on title band and hide header band or image for the first page

Comment: Yes, If I use title then the image will get print only on the first page but I need the image on each page.

Comment: `I need the image on each page` - Sure, you should use both (title & page header) bands for showing image

Comment: Yes I was asking this how to hide the page header for the first page but it will get printed from the second page?

Comment: As usual, using printWhenExpression and $V{PAGE_NUMBER}

Comment: Ya this worked for me  >> $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()!= 1